# Using window.getSelection to get a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `window.getSelection` to get a string but it's returning an object.

```
var text = '';
text = document.getSelection();
alert(typeof(text)); //object
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.getSelection()` returns a DOMSelection object. The [DOMSelection class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/selection#Introduction) contains a `.toString()` method to turn it into a string.

So

```
var str = window.getSelection().toString();
alert(typeof(str));  // string.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Where can i found full of javascript "class" .

Answer (score 3):

`getSelection` returns a [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection) object. You can get the selected text by calling its `toString` method.

Answer (score 3):

```
text = document.getSelection()+'';
alert(typeof(text)); // << it returns string
```