# Weird javascript variable string / DOMSelection?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a weird variable that when alerted seams to be a string but in the console it is a DOMSelection (in tree form) how can I get access the the string from the console.

```
DOMSelection
anchorNode: Text
anchorOffset: 36
baseNode: Text
baseOffset: 36
extentNode: Text
extentOffset: 40
focusNode: Text
focusOffset: 40
isCollapsed: false
rangeCount: 1
type: "Range"
__proto__: DOMSelection
```

Comment: have you tried console.log(obj.toString()); ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getSelection Javascript . I want to get string , not object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417784/getselection-javascript-i-want-to-get-string-not-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call toString() on it according to https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Selection

Answer (score 1):

If when alerted this object appears to be a string, that means it has a special `toString` method defined which serializes its contents into a string representation. So to get that string you can just call:

```
myObject.toString();
```